# How to check that no file is uploaded to server via form?

Tags: html, content-disposition

I have next form:

```html
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <input name="example" type="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

On server side I see that file of size zero is uploaded:

```
-----------------------------23370864791729106148808009039
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="example"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------23370864791729106148808009039--
```

How can I check that nothing was selected by user for this `file` field?

Comment: In a simple way, you can add a 'required' property to your file field.

Answer (score 0):

Add `required` to your input field to make sure an element has been uploaded.

```html
 <form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <input required name="example" type="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
 </form
```

You can also check via javascript if there is a content given if you don't want to use the required attribute:

```js
 function hasContent() {
     let fileValue = document.getElementsByName('example')[0].value;
     alert(fileValue !== '' ? "has content" : 'no content');
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"method="POST">
     <input name="example"type="file">
     <input type="button"value="Upload"onclick="hasContent();">
</form>
```

Comment: There is no requirement to upload file. But on the server side I do not know how to check user select or not select file.

Comment: @Eugen Konkov: I edited my answer for an javascript content check. Although javascript is client-side, this will work. If you don't say what server-side technology you are using and if you don't show any of your tries, I can not help you further than that.

Comment: As you can see browser sends data in MIME encoded info. How can I realize on server side from this MIME info that user does not fill this input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code into your php file after submit:

```html
if($_FILES['example']['tmp_name'] != null){
    //Actions you needed
}
```

If it returns true it means the file is selected.

Comment: May you provide link to official info?

Comment: Yes this link is good reference for your question answer [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)